# Having Issues With Logging Into red hat linux in single user mode

Tags: linux

I recently did a mysql database dump on a server, without realizing it was almost full. Now i can not login, and get the error: "out of disk space". the issue is that i want to log in using the single user mode in order to delete some files, but whenever i execute the command to login using run level 1
     (from the grub menu, by typing single at the end of the

```
     "kernel/boot/xen.gz-2.6.18-8.el5"
```

option),
 it still takes me to run level 5. How can i solve this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the grub menu by pressing Esc, edit the command line, append `init=/bin/bash`.

Note that only / will be mounted, and what's more it will be mounted read-only. Type `mount -n -o remount,rw /` first thing if you need to access it read write.

Comment: when i do this, will i now be able to access my desktop using the ls command?

Comment: when i type init=/bin/bash...it gives an "unrecognized command" error